# Ad for Stack Overflow jobs within Google summary

Tags: bug, google

[image]

When googling about a programming-related topic, Google gave me a summary quoting a snippet from Stack Overflow. However, the image on the right hand side isn't very helpful - it's about Stack Overflow jobs, rather than about sockets, or about Stack Overflow itself.

Stack Overflow should provide a more relevant image, or no image at all, to Google.

Comment: Agreed - *if* they have control over this, which they may not.

Comment: If they don't have control over that, there's a "Feedback" link under the summary, presumably for providing this kind of feedback.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think employees of Stack Exchange would be able to provide more detailed and informative feedback than I would.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking "they", meaning SO, would use the Feedback link.

Comment: The image says "Find your dream job". It's clear it's not about sockets.

Comment: @Oriol it seems to be about the cloud.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Text summarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization) is a subtask of [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) and [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) and is done by the Google search engine **automatically** via machine learning techniques (which are not yet mature enough to have a great accuracy in complex tasks like this).

Anyway, this has nothing to do with Stack Overflow! If you're not satisfied with the result that Google search engine provides, you may:

- **Send feedback to Google**:
  As some have suggested in comments, there is a "Feedback" link under the summary that you and many other can use. It can really be helpful if many people use it as some machine learning techniques consider feedback from the environment in their calculations.
- **Solve it yourself:**

  1. Provide a general solution (not just about Stack Overflow) for this task.
  2. Publish it as a paper in a reputable journal.
  3. Talk Google into using it.
  4. Wait for it to kick in!
- **Ultimately** if it is really annoying, you may consider using other search engines.

By the way, many researchers and I would REALLY appreciate the second approach.

### Edit:

> I assume Stack Exchange would be better at sending useful, informative
>   feedback to Google than I would.

It makes sense what you say, but I personally don't think that helps a lot. As most machine learning algorithms learn patterns from data not procedures, it could be very complicated to enforce conditions like `if (stackoverflow) then do...`. For those, Google probably have to add some labeled data which forces the condition and let the algorithms pick them up. But there may be need for significant amount of labeled data for this to have a meaningful effect and I don't think they do it because:

- It could be labor intensive.
- Google can't/won't address every website's personal specific issues unless there is a big law suit involved.
- There already is a mechanism (feedback link) to address these problems.

Comment: An amusing answer (in a good way), but I assume Stack Exchange would be better at sending useful, informative feedback to Google than I would.

Comment: it's a good point but in my opinion it's not likely to have a siginificant effect. Please see my update.